# Document ready issues in java script file

Tags: javascript

I am writing one function called test function inside external java script file.
inside document ready function, i write one function which is not accessible from another java script declared in another html page and calling from outside document ready  function and if I declared function test function outside document ready then its working properly.

Comment: this is not an issue, you are declaring a function inside of a closure.

Comment: sorry for the incomplete answer, by doing what you are doing you are declaring the function inside of a closure: `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work` and that function will only be available within that closure

Comment: Is any another method to call that function? Or it is impossible in that closure

Comment: maybe if you return a reference to the function from the closure

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of things to note here:

\1 Function names are variables with a function assigned as their value. So, the following two things are practically the same:

```
function my_func = function () {
    alert('Hello World!');
};

var my_func = function () {
    alert('Hello World!');
};
```

\2 Variable scoping in javascript: variables declared inside of a closure are visible only to that closure.  However, a closure has access to variables declared in a higher scope. So, the following will not work:

```
var my_func = function () {
    var my_second_func = function () { alert ('hello');};
};
my_func();
my_second_func(); // not declared
```

But the following will work:

```
var my_second_func; // declare the variable in the global scope
var my_func = function () {
    my_second_func = function () { alert ('hello');};
};
my_func();
my_second_func(); // will alert "hello"
```

Note where the `var` keywords are.  These declare a variable in the current scope.  If you want to be absolutely sure that the function is available in the global scope, declare it this way:

```
window.my_function = function () {
    // do something
};
```

However, this is generally considered bad practice and should be used *sparingly*.